# Changing font size of a specific portion of the overall document

Tags: equations, fontsize

I have to write a paper for one of my classes and I have what I'm sure is a very basic question that I can't seem to find the answer for.  Basically, I just want to be able to increase the font size of some equations because the default size is a bit too small in my opinion.  I only want to change the font size for the code listed below, not for the entire document.  I am still very new to Latex so the code is probably a mess.

```
\begin{center}  
{C\textsubscript{n}}=$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}$  
\hspace{1.5cm}  
{C\textsubscript{n}}=$\frac{1}{n+1}$$\binom{2n}{n}$  
\hspace{1.5cm}  
{C\textsubscript{n}}=$\binom{2n}{n}$-$\binom{2n}{n+1}$  
\end{center}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package?

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use one of the `align*` or `\alignat*`  environments: you'll have your fractions and binomial coefficients in \displaystyle. The latter environment gives you full control on the spacing between the groups. You also can use the medium-sized commands from `nccmath` (~ 80% of \displaystyle). Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{C}_{n} & =\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!\,n!}
 &
\mathrm{C}_{n} &= \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}
 &
\mathrm{C}_{n} &=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n+1}
\end{align*}\bigskip

\begin{alignat*}{3}
\mathrm{C}_{n} & =\mfrac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!\,n!}
 &\hspace{1cm}
\mathrm{C}_{n} &= \mfrac{1}{n+1} \mbinom{2n}{n}
 &\hspace{1cm}
\mathrm{C}_{n} &=\mbinom{2n}{n}-\mbinom{2n}{n+1}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the input!  This should get me on my way.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to adjust the font size, but in this case I think what you are after is "displayed math," which will (a) center the equation automatically, and (b) use a larger font. You can get displayed math mode by wrapping your math in `$$`...`$$`, or `\[`...`\]`, or `\begin{equation*}`...`\end{equation*}`, or (if you want equation numbers) `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[C_n = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}\]
\begin{equation*} C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} \end{equation*}
\begin{equation} C_n = \binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n+1} \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And as @Bernard said, align is a good option if you want to vertically align the equal signs. There are lots of LaTeX environments for doing this; see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Vertically_aligning_displayed_mathematics.

Comment: And as @Bernard said, `align` is a good option if you want to vertically align the equal signs. There are lots of LaTeX environments for doing this; see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Vertically_aligning_displayed_mathematics.

Comment: Maybe you should add the content this comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I should be good to go with this issue now.